# Error Fetching hashmap value from c++ using JNI from java

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have created a hashmap class which contains details of process name , id and its usage and using hashentry class I've stored values for each Table[i].
Problem is i'can access upto HASHMAP class cant go upto HASHENTRY error occurs.

My NATIVE code in CPlusPlus :

```
//ProcessManagement.h

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_newjni_JNITest_sayHello (JNIEnv*, jobject)
{
    printf("HelloWorld\n");
    HashMap hash;
    int x = hash.get(3);
    printf("%d", x);
    return;
}


 // ProcessInfo.h

 // In hashmapentry class
 .
 .
 .
   HashEntry(int ke, int valu, string nam, int memusag, int cpuusag, double 
    diskusag, double netusag, string unam) {

    this->key = ke;

    this->value = valu;

    this->name = nam;

    this->memusage = memusag;

    this->cpuusage = cpuusag;

    this->diskusage = diskusag;

    this->netusage= netusag;

    this->uname= unam;
  }


   //In hashMap class
   .
   .
   .
     void put(int ke, int valu, string nam, int memusag, int cpuusag, double 
     diskusag, double netusag, string use) {

    int hash = ke;

    table[hash] = new HashEntry(ke, valu, nam, memusag, cpuusag, diskusag, 
    netusag, use);

    }






  //ProcessManagement.cpp
  .
  .
  //used windows api to get values of process

   hash.put(i, (int)pid[i], pname, memusage, cpuusage[i], diskusage, netusage, 
   s);

  .
  .
  .
```

In JAVA :

```
 public class JNITest {  // Save as HelloJNI.java
 static {
    System.loadLibrary("ProcessHash"); 

}


 private native void sayHello();
 private native void print();


 public static void main(String[] args) {

    new JNITest().sayHello();  // Create an instance and invoke the native method
 }
 }
```

And the error occurs for me is :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
 #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffcf33417dd, pid=12584, tid=4912
#
# JRE version: 6.0_32-b05
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.7-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ProcessHash.dll+0x217dd]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\MrBean\Documents\NetBeansProjects\newJNI\hs_err_pid12584.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
HelloWorld
```

ERROR LOG : https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/356y

Comment: attach contents of hs_err_pid12584.log to the question

Comment: In the code you've shown us, you attempt to get something out of a newly created HashMap (which one would assume is empty). What are you expecting to get from an empty HashMap?

Comment: How do we know your "HashMap" actually works?  Did you test this with a simple C++ program?

Comment: Why not use `std::map<int, HashEntry>` ?

Comment: used st::map<int, HashEntry>..

how to return this hashmap to java?
and i need to print those values in java...